# HTML Frame/Border/Lines won't go away

Tags: html

[grey lines around my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y77x5.png)

I can't get these grey lines (they go all the way around the table) to go away in my website. When I preview them from the editor, they're not there. I should mention that I am not proficient (or even sufficient) in any code language, I am just trying to update my company's website to be more visually appealing - total novice. I have tried every option I can find online including setting the table, table row, & table data to 0. I've set the border color to #ffffff. I've coded for a border collapse at all three levels as well. I've set the cellspacing and cellpadding to 0. I even encased the whole table in a div with a style set border at 0. I just cannot figure it out. I tried using CSS since everything online says it's way better than tables, but it didn't take the code. Can anyone help me figure this out?

My code is below, but I deleted a bunch of the unnecessary content from the bullet list. There is more content on the page, though, above and below the table.

```
<table>
  <tbody width="100%">
    <tr><td width="50%;" style="text-align:left;">
      <ul>
        <li><span style=" font-size: 18px;">9V, AAA and AA batteries</span>
        </li>
        <li><span style="font-size: 18px;">baby bath tubs/bathers</span></li>  
    </ul></td>
    <td width="50%;" style="text-align:left;" valign="top">
      <ul>
        <li><span style="font-size: 18px;">infant/toddler easy-dissolving 
        snacks</span></li>
        <li><span style="font-size: 18px;">infant/toddler socks</span></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It seems that a stylesheet (application-0a96c182667ef1f131d00f5eae9248bcc745113f552ab58cd6d8279212de1fad.css) sets `table td {border:1px solid #e0e0e0}`. Notice that this style is set on the table *cells* (`<td>`). You can overwrite that definition with `table td {border:none}` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the developer tools, you will easily find that there is a class in `/assets/application-0a96c182667ef1f131d00f5eae9248bcc745113f552ab58cd6d8279212de1fad.css` that is setting the table cell border to `1px solid #e0e0e0`

```
table td {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you want to override this behavior, but only for this table, you can set the table's class attribute:

```
<table class="no-border" ...>
...
</table>
```

and create a new class like this

```
table.no-border td {
    border: 0;
}
```

I strongly recommend you learn how to use the developer tools of your favorite browser, for example [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Comment: Thanks, @ncardeli, I can see this, but don't know how to make the change in the DevTool for Chrome (the browser I use). Like I said, I'm very new. As in, I have zero experience and am teaching myself as I go. It won't maintain my changes, so perhaps I need to make them elsewhere?

Comment: As you already noticed, the changes you make in the dev tools are not saved. To make the changes, you have to edit the CSS file and add the class I suggest in my answer. You will also have to edit the html page to add the `class` attribute to the table. I took a look at the page and noticed that you already added the class, but with a semicolon. Delete the semicolon.

Comment: If you can't edit the CSS file for whatever reason, you can always add a style tag to the page, that will be local to that page. To add a tag style with my suggested CSS rule, add this inside the head of the page: `<style>table.no-border td { border: 0;}</style>`

Comment: I took out the semicolon and added a line with <style>table.no-border td { border: 0;}</style> and it worked! It's so gratifying to see those lines gone! THANK YOU! I appreciate your patience and hand-holding with me. --Karissa